# Android browser showing 1920x1080 content

Tags: android

I've built browser app and trying to show 1920x1080 web page. I'm using ICS 4.0.3 and external 1080p screen, but android itself doesn't seem to be able to use resolutions over 1280x800, even thou it states resolution as 1080p in display settings. Is this a common issue? Are there any android ICS versions that support 1080p output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ASUS Transformer Pad Infinity](http://eee.asus.com/eeepad/transformer-infinity/features/) and [Acer A700](http://www.engadget.com/2012/01/08/acer-iconia-tab-a700-hands-on/) both support 1080p. Additionally, [Google TV](http://www.google.com/tv/) runs on a version of Android and [supports 1080p](http://www.google.com/tv/features.html). I suspect that your device simply does not actually support running at 1080p and instead only upscales its output.

Answer (score 0):

The standard android kernel is not able to allocate the memory needed for the framebuffer at such high resolution.

Comment: Just curious, not saying you're wrong, but do you have a reference for that?

Comment: You can check the logcat and see the error when the allocation fails (if it fails)

Comment: Found a [reference](http://www.omappedia.com/wiki/Android_How-tos#Memory_Allocation) with some Googling. It doesn't sound like it's the kernel itself per se, but merely some boot configuration.